# VBA is copying the range of three cells and saving it to another file how do i get it to increment the range

Tags: vba, excel

My VBA code is being feed input from a scanner that scans a barcode that then inputs three pieces of information into cells A1 B1 and C1. The first time around it works fine, however after I try to do it on the row below it doesn't work. I know it has something to do with the range I am selecting, but I don't know how to increment a range.  this is my code so far :

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim String_1 As String
Dim String_2 As String
Dim String_3 As String

String_1 = "400"
String_2 = "401"
String_3 = "402"

If Len(Range("A1").Value) > 0 And Len(Range("B1").Value) > 0 And Len(Range("C1").Value) > 0 Then

Dim sComp As String
sComp = Left(Range("C1"), 3)

 If sComp = String_1 Or sComp = String_2 Or sComp = String_3 Then

    Range("A1:C1").Copy
    Dim wbCopy As Workbook
    Set wbCopy = Workbooks.Add

    With wbCopy
        .Sheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        .SaveAs Filename:="u:\CSV\Diepunch" & sComp & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        .Close False

    End With

  End If

End If

End Sub
```

I need this to work so every time there is a different number getting triggered by the one of the strings the right data is saved into the correct file. Anyone have any insight on how to fix this or tips? The help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the next empty row to paste the data.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim String_1 As String
    Dim String_2 As String
    Dim String_3 As String
    Dim newRow As Long
    String_1 = "400"
    String_2 = "401"
    String_3 = "402"

    If Len(Range("A1").Value) > 0 And Len(Range("B1").Value) > 0 And Len(Range("C1").Value) > 0 Then

        Dim sComp As String
        sComp = Left(Range("C1"), 3)

        If sComp = String_1 Or sComp = String_2 Or sComp = String_3 Then

            Range("A1:C1").Copy
            Dim wbCopy As Workbook
            Set wbCopy = Workbooks.Add

            With wbCopy
                newRow = .Range("A1").End(xlUp).Row + 1
                .Sheets(1).Cells(newRow, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                .SaveAs Filename:="u:\CSV\Diepunch" & sComp & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
                Application.DisplayAlerts = True
                .Close False

            End With

        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: it still isn't working, the first time around it works fine, however after the second bar-code is scanned for some reason excel is copying the row above and pasting it as the save file, then the active cell is in the C column below the most recent added data in the cells above.

Answer (score 0):

you must both check for the existence of the CSV file to update and find its last row to append new data after it

a quick and dirty fix:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim String_1 As String
    Dim String_2 As String
    Dim String_3 As String
    Dim myFileName As String

    Dim wbCopy As Workbook
    Dim lastRow As Long

    String_1 = "400"
    String_2 = "401"
    String_3 = "402"

    If Len(Range("A1").Value) > 0 And Len(Range("B1").Value) > 0 And Len(Range("C1").Value) > 0 Then

        Dim sComp As String
        sComp = Left(Range("C1"), 3)

        If sComp = String_1 Or sComp = String_2 Or sComp = String_3 Then
'            myFileName = "u:\CSV\Diepunch" & sComp & ".csv"
            Range("A1:C1").Copy

            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            If Dir(myFileName) = "" Then
                Set wbCopy = Workbooks.Add
            Else
                Set wbCopy = Workbooks.Open(myFileName)
            End If

            With wbCopy
                With .Sheets(1)
                    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
                    If .Cells(lastRow, 1).Value <> "" Then lastRow = lastRow + 1
                    .Cells(lastRow, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                End With
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                .SaveAs Filename:=myFileName, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
                Application.DisplayAlerts = True
                .Close False
            End With

            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        End If

    End If

End Sub
```